# I want to access the variable outeside the if() iterator

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want the get the current value in if() out of the if loop.

ex:-

```
$('.name').each(function () {
    //name = this;
    temp = parseInt($('#slide_here').next().val());
    //console.log(temp)
    if (($(this).hasClass("1") == true)) {
        //console.log("you in1")
        //console.log(temp);
        if (temp > 10 && temp <= 20) {
            temp = temp + 10;
            //console.log(temp);
            //Agriculture.push(10);
        } else {
            temp = temp + 5;
            //console.log(temp);
            //Agriculture.push(5);
        }
        //return temp;
        console.log(temp);
    }
    if (($(this).hasClass("2") == true)) {
        console.log("you in2")
        if (temp > 10 && temp <= 20) {
            console.log(temp);
            temp = temp + 10;
            //Industry.push(10);
        } else {
            temp = temp + 5;
            //Industry.push(5);
        }
        //return temp;
    }
```

value should get added to the temp while iterating the if loop. i want final value as total addition after executing the all if statement.
example

initially
temp=13
in first if loop
temp=23
i want this 23 value for next if statement. I tried but i am getting 13 value only.

Comment: There are several if blocks and several variables.  Please clarify.  Also, if is not an iterator.

Comment: do the `.name` classed elements have either of those two classes `1` or `2` you are looking for? not a good idea to name classes by numbers. also, please post your HTML

Comment: Before I have posted answer, there was a return statement. You ave uncommented it

Comment: iwnt value out of main if (($(this).hasClass("1") == true)) {}

Comment: `if` is not a loop and since you are getting only the value 13 in the second `if`, it is not going into the first `if` block.

Comment: yes there was a return statement,,,,,,,

Comment: yah its going to the first if statement,,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your assignment outside for global variable. In your code, when value is bigger than 20, it is not entering if statement. In order to make enter inside second if, I have updated condition to see global variable is remains same value as last updated;

```
var temp = parseInt($('#slide_here').next().val());

$('.name').each(function () {
            //name = this;



            //console.log(temp)

            if (($(this).hasClass("1") == true)) {

                //console.log("you in1")
                //console.log(temp);
                if (temp > 10 && temp <= 20) {
                    temp = temp + 10;
                    //console.log(temp);
                    //Agriculture.push(10);
                } else {
                    temp = temp + 5;
                    //console.log(temp);
                    //Agriculture.push(5);
                }
                //return temp;
                console.log(temp);

            }

            if (($(this).hasClass("2") == true)) {

                console.log("you in2")
                if (temp > 10 && temp <= 20) {
                    console.log(temp);
                    temp = temp + 10;
                    //Industry.push(10);
                } else {
                    temp = temp + 5;
                    //Industry.push(5);
                }
                //return temp;
            }
```

You can see demo here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/X4ZGx/1/)**

Comment: downvote owner, before posting my answer, there was a return statement. It was uncommented

Comment: @scrowler there is no `var` before `temp` in the OP code inside the `each` callback, so a global it must be.  The issue might be that temp is reset to the slider value at the beginning of every `each` callback.

Comment: You are wrong . See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/X4ZGx/ check console and you will see it is 23 in second iteration

Comment: in second if 23 value of previous if should get added to second if temp that means it should be 23+5=28 because condition false.

Comment: But I have put alert before them. See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/X4ZGx/2/

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct. The only issue I see is that you check whether temp is less than 21, but it is now 23, so it will not enter the last if. Add some alerts to debug it. Here is what worked fine for me:

```
        $('.name').each(function ()
        {
            //name = this;
            temp = 13;
            alert("begins with" + temp);
            //console.log(temp)

            if (($(this).hasClass("1") == true))
            {
                //console.log("you in1")
                //console.log(temp);
                if (temp > 10 && temp <= 20)
                {
                    temp = temp + 10;
                    alert("temp modified to: " + temp);
                    //console.log(temp);
                    //Agriculture.push(10);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = temp + 5;
                    //console.log(temp);
                    //Agriculture.push(5);
                }
                //return temp;
                console.log(temp);
                alert("in first if: " + temp);
            }

            if (($(this).hasClass("2") == true))
            {
                console.log("you in2")
                if (temp > 10 && temp <= 20)
                {
                    console.log(temp);
                    alert("current value should match the previous alert: " + temp);
                    temp = temp + 10;
                    //Industry.push(10);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = temp + 5;
                    //Industry.push(5);
                }
                alert("in second if: " + temp);
                //return temp;
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: in second if 23 value of previous if should get added to second if temp that means it should be 23+5=28 because condition false

Answer (score 0):

`if` statements are not loops - they execute once (depending on whether the condition is true or not) and there is no iteration.

The loop in your code is actually the call to jQuery `each` in this line:

```
$('.name').each(function () {
```

If you want the value of `temp` to be updated in the loop without being reset for each element with class `name`, you probably need to move the declaration of the `temp` variable outside of the loop:

```
var temp = parseInt($('#slide_here').next().val());

$('.name').each(function () {
    if (($(this).hasClass("1") == true)) {
        // ... do logic and update temp
    }
    if (($(this).hasClass("2") == true)) {
        // ... do logic and update temp
    }
}

// use final temp value
```

Comment: for first if statement its working fine,,,,,,,,,, but for next if statement value is not getting updated.

Comment: Are you sure that the element has both "1" and "2" classes? You could check that both conditions are evaluating to true by adding a console.log or alert call inside each if block.